# PDF to SVG: Inkscape distorts images

Tags: pdf, svg, png, inkscape

I'm trying to convert a PDF generated by Latex to an svg. In the latex I include some images using `\includegraphics{someimage.png}`. The resulting pdf looks fine.

However, when I convert to svg using inkscape, the images get distorted. Does anyone know why? The command I use is `inkscape --file=test.pdf --export-plain-svg=output.svg`.

Edit:
The tex code is

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{face.jpg}
\end{document}
```

and some image (here a jpg, but problems also for png)

[image].

The reslting pdf is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qp81i6ote9w919/test.pdf?dl=1)

The result after the command:

https://jsfiddle.net/z0r712xu/

Comment: without links to the PDF, to someimage.png, and maybe even the tex file used to generate it, we won't be able to help you. PDF is **not** a format to exchange *editable* documents, so that kind of explains it. If you want my opinion, going through pdflatex is the wrong choice here – use latex instead of pdflatex -> dvips -> pstoedit -> inkscape, like the latex render extension for inkscape does.

Answer (score 0):

My version of inkscape (0.91 r13725) adds the line

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

after the image data. This restores the correct appearance in the jsfiddle example.